# Automatically generate file name from text boxes in layout in QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, qgis-print-layouts

Suppose I have a layout template in QGIS, with a lot of text boxes like the title of the map, title of the project, a project code, ...

When I export a map in pdf, is it possible to have it named automatically in a name like "Projectcode + Title + Date".pdf ?

If so, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

**If the values are included in your layer:**

you can call them in the printcomposer by going to tab 'Atlas generation'.  In the section 'Output' you can define the outputname.  In your example it would be:

```
"Projectcode" ||'_' || "Title" || '_' || day(now())|| '-' || month(now()) || '-' || year(now())
```

Which gives the result Projectcode_Title_15-01-2019

You can even automaticly add those features in your textboxes by choosing 'insert an expression' in the itemproperties of the textbox.

**If the values ar NOT included in a layer:**

Add project-variables: go to project > projectproperties (or press Ctrl+Shift+P)

In the section 'variables' add 2 new entries by clicking the green '+' in the right corner.  Give them the name 'Projectcode' and 'Title'.  Add a value for both.

Now you can call those variables everywhere in your project, also in the composer.

Add the desired textboxes and add following expressions: `[% @Projectcode %]` and `[% @Title%]`

For the outputfilename it gives you folowing expression:

```
@Projectcode ||'_' || @Title || '_' || day(now())|| '-' || month(now()) || '-' || year(now())
```

Comment: Hi Pieter, I do not have columns with these names, just textboxes on my layout, how do I link to those?

Comment: it is not possible to link textboxes to the outputfilename.  But there is another option with project-variables.  I will edit my answer